# Increasing invoke spawn speed using enumerator

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to increase the spawn time of an invoke function, I'm using an IEnumerator but it's not working.

It looks like the system reads the starting spawnSpeed value and not changing it reading the IE function.
I'm not aware if there is another way to make this work.

Plz, help.

this is my code:

```
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstaclesController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obstacle;
    private GameObject obstacleClone;
    public Transform ObstacleMarker;
    private float CloneLifeTime = 4f;
    float spawnSpeed;
    float spawnInterval = 3;
    float minSpawn = -4;
    float maxSpawn = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        spawnSpeed = 2f;
        StartCoroutine("IncreaseSpeedWithInterval");
        InvokeRepeating("AddingObstacle", spawnSpeed, spawnSpeed);
    }

    IEnumerator IncreaseSpeedWithInterval()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(spawnInterval);

            spawnSpeed *= 1.5f;
        }
    }

    private void AddingObstacle()
    {
        float randomLocation = Random.Range(minSpawn, maxSpawn);

        obstacleClone = Instantiate(obstacle, ObstacleMarker.position, ObstacleMarker.rotation);
        obstacleClone.transform.position = new Vector3(ObstacleMarker.transform.position.x, randomLocation, ObstacleMarker.transform.position.z);

        Destroy(obstacleClone, CloneLifeTime);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(spawnSpeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested if the IEnumerator is running? Like putting a debug.log inside it?

Comment: Also I think Invoke takes in the parameter as a value not as a reference, hence it always remains at 2s, I might be wrong however

Answer (score 1):

After the call to

```
InvokeRepeating("AddingObstacle", spawnSpeed, spawnSpeed);
```

any later change on `spawnSpeed` has no effect whatsoever .. a `float` is passed by **value** and there is no connection between the passed one and the one you later adjust!

---

You can instead wrap it into another Coroutine like

```
private IEnumerator AddingObstacleRoutine()
{
    while(true)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnSpeed);

        AddingObstacle();
    }
}
```

And instead start this routine as well using

```
StartCoroutine(IncreaseSpeedWithInterval());
StartCoroutine(AddingObstacleRoutine());
```